# A custom Sqlite function behaves differently on 32-bit and 64-bit systems

Tags: c, sqlite, 32bit-64bit

I am using a custom [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) Sqlite function in a project. Here's a link to the function:

https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder/blob/master/src/libsqlite3_geocoder/metaphon.c

When I run the function on 32-bit Ubuntu, executing something like:

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
sqlite> .load ./libsqlite3_geocoder.so 
sqlite> select metaphone('hitchcock');
XKK
```

As you can see, the function returned invalid result (correct result is `HXKK`). On 64-bit Ubuntu, this error doesn't occur.

Oddly enough, if I compile this function as a standalone C program (remove all Sqlite stuff), it works OK on 32-bit OS too.

Any ideas what could be the reason and how to fix it?

Note: if you want to try it yourself, just get the [code](https://github.com/geocommons/geocoder) from Github, run `make` in `src/libsqlite3_geocoder` directory and `.so` should be built. You need sqlite3 development library to compile it though.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. There's a bug in `metaphone()` function, where at one point it checks a character outside the bounds of the given string, which obviously return different values in different situations (not sure if that's related to whether OS is 32-bit or 64-bit):

```
case 'H':
    if (!varson(*(n - 1)) && (!vowel(*(n - 1)) || // see that "n - 1" here!
                               vowel(*(n + 1))))
    {
        *Metaph++ = 'H';
    }
    break;
```